# How to use Combine to show elastic search results using network while falling back on cache in Swift

Tags: swift, caching, search, combine, publisher

I have a function which returns a list of Items using elastic search and falls back on realm cache. I'm wondering how can I use `Combine` to achieve the same.

I am trying to do something like this where I have a publisher for each store but I am getting stuck on the sorting them by score.

```
    func search(for text: String) -> AnyPublisher<[Item], Error> {
          
          return store.search(with: text)
            // Invalid syntax *
            .map { searchResults in
                let sorted = cacheStore.search(with: text)
                    .map { items in
                        items
                            .map { item in (item, searchResults.first { $0.id == item.id }?.score ?? 0) }
                            .sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 } // by score
                            .map { $0.0 } // to item
                    }
                return sorted.eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            // *
            .catch { _ in cacheStore.search(with: text) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

This is the original function.

```
func search(for text: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Item], Error>) -> Void) {
  
    store.search(with: text) {
        // Search network via elastic search or fall back to cache search
        // searchResults is of type [(id: Int, score: Double)] where id is item.id
        guard let searchResult = $0.value, $0.isSuccess else {
            return self.cacheStore.search(with: text, completion: completion)
        }
        
        self.cacheStore.fetch(ids: searchResult.map { $0.id }) {
            guard let items = $0.value, $0.isSuccess else {
                return self.cacheStore.search(with: text, completion: completion)
            }
            
            let scoredItems = items
                .map { item in (item, searchResult.first { $0.id == item.id }?.score ?? 0) }
                .sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 } // by score
                .map { $0.0 } // to item
            
            completion(.success(scoredItems))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution by doing something like this:

```
    let cachedPublisher = cacheStore.search(with: text)
    
    let createPublisher: (Item) -> AnyPublisher<Item, Error> = {
        return Just($0).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    return store.search(with: request)
        .flatMap { Item -> AnyPublisher<[Item], Error> in
            let ids = searchResults.map { $0.id }
            let results = self.cacheStore.fetch(ids: ids, filterActive: true)
                .flatMap { items -> AnyPublisher<[Item], Error> in
                    let sorted = items
                        .map { item in (item, searchResults.first { $0.id == item.id }?.score ?? 0) }
                        .sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 } // by score
                        .map{ $0.0 } // to item
                    return Publishers.mergeMappedRetainingOrder(sorted, mapTransform: createPublisher) // Helper function that calls Publishers.MergeMany
                }
            return results.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .catch { _ in cachedPublisher }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are aiming for is something like the Playground below.

Most of the playground is code is code that mocks up searches using `Futures`. The particularly relevant section is:

```
return searchNetwork(key: key)
    .map { key,value in cache[key] = value; return value }
    .catch {_ in searchCache(key: key) }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

If the network request from `searchNetwork` succeeds then the value passes through the map which adds it to the cache and returns the value from the network.  If `searchNetwork` fails then `catch` will substitute the publisher that searches the cache.

```
import Foundation
import Combine

var cache = [
    "one" : "for the money",
    "two" : "for the show"
]

enum SearchError: Error {
    case cacheMiss
    case networkFailure
}

func searchCache(key : String) -> AnyPublisher<String, SearchError>
{
    return Future<String, SearchError> { fulfill in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) {
            if let value = cache[key] {
                fulfill(.success(value))
            } else {
                fulfill(.failure(.cacheMiss))
            }
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func searchNetwork(key: String) -> AnyPublisher<(String, String), SearchError> {
    return Future<(String, String), SearchError> { fulfill in
        fulfill(.failure(.networkFailure))
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func search(for key: String) -> AnyPublisher<String, SearchError> {
    return searchNetwork(key: key)
        .map { key,value in cache[key] = value; return value }
        .catch {_ in searchCache(key: key) }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

let searchForOne = search(for: "one").sink(
    receiveCompletion:  { debugPrint($0) },
    receiveValue: { print("Search for one : \($0)") }
)

let searchForThree = search(for: "three").sink(
    receiveCompletion: { debugPrint($0) },
    receiveValue: { print("Search for three : \($0)") }
)
```

Comment: Interesting, yes in my case the Items are already saved in my Realm database so 
 for this line ".map { key,value in cache[key] = value; return value }". I'm struggling to see how to use the network publisher (AnyPublisher<[SearchResult], Error>) which are a list of id's with scores to filter the Realm publisher (AnyPublisher<[Item], Error>) to return a publisher with sorted Items by score. So basically I'm just using the network publisher to retrieve the scores and trying to filter the Realm publisher using those scores.

Comment: I also updated my question with your input in mind but the syntax is invalid